# Downloading TinyMCE Plugins for Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I am using the TinyMCE rails gem, but I can't find any TinyMCE plugins (such as bullist, or any other plugin). Anyone else using TinyMCE gem with rails that knows how to get different plugins such as these to work? I posted in the TinyMCE forum but I have had no luck with a reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying it out. So far I've been able to get a few of the plugins to work with my config/tinymce.yml file. Mine looks like this:

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: top
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
theme_advanced_statusbar_location: bottom
theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
  - tablecontrols
  - fullscreen
  - media
  - preview
  - link
  - image

plugins:
  - table
  - fullscreen
  - preview
  - media
  - link
  - image
```

I'm using http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php as a reference. Probably not the most in depth answer but I hope it helps out.